# dateFormatter does not handle invalid hour

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am using **NSDateFormatter** in my app. It works fine as long as the user enters the correct date and time.

But suppose if user enters some invalid time, for e.g 100:00 hours , then the date formatter returns NSDate as nil.
I used the following code for date formatter:

> NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
>
> ```
> [dateFormat setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
>
> [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
> ```
>
> NSDate *startdate = [dateFormat dateFromString:start];

```
NSDate *enddate = [dateFormat dateFromString:end];
```

"start" and "end" are the strings with user entered data which are combination of date and time. But the date I get from dateFromString in case of invalid hours entered by user is nil.I want to catch this invalid hours/time issue in someway and
get the correct date and time?

Can anyone suggest some pointers?

Comment: you may add more code..

Comment: and which is the correct date? what if user put: 213:00 hours? you just can guess choosing 21:00 or 13:00 or what else? I'd just check the number of chars and let him repeat the input untill he give correct format

Comment: Its a suggestion.. Instead of having the user enter it manually , you can create a date picker control and the user can select it from there. No need for any validation and the date will always be correctly selected..

Comment: Yes, Using date picker is the way.